# Instagram Photos array with all photos to array of selected photos

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, instagram

I'm trying to set up my Instagram API site so that users can select photos

I am able to save the data in an database and Display the photos but not able to make photos selectable in an different array

Here's my code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require 'db.php';   
    require 'instagram.class.php';
    require 'instagram.config.php';

    if (!empty($_SESSION['userdetails']))
    {
        $data=$_SESSION['userdetails'];

        // Store user access token      
        $instagram->setAccessToken($data);

    }
    else
    {   
        header('Location: index.php');
    }

    ?>


    <?php

    $popular = $instagram->getUserMedia($data->user->id);

    // Display results
    foreach ($popular->data as $data)
    {
        echo "<img src=\"{$data->images->thumbnail->url}\";">
    }                                       
?>
```

Comment: What does "make photos selectable" mean?

Comment: @eluong: from the list/array of photos user can select the photos he likes.
list/array of photos

`code`        echo "<img src=\"{$data->images->thumbnail->url}\";">                         }                                         `code`

Comment: This seems like two very unrelated questions mashed into one.  The first question about making images selectable has nothing to do with making a function to send emails.

Comment: removed question no 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot make the images "selectable" with php, you need to do that with some javascript and css styles

```
img.selected {
  border:solid 1px green;
}
```

Then with some javascript, you can find all the images with `document.images` or `document.getElementsByTagName('img')`.  It would be best if you gave them all a class to select from `document.getElementsByClassName('insta-photos')` where the images `class` attribute is `insta-photos`

...once you have the list of images, you can add some event handling for the "selection", all you have to do is unselect all the other images (ie remove the `selected` class from all of the images) and select the current one by updating its css class to "selected"

Ultimately with php, you could put a link around each image that did roundtrips from the client and the server, displaying the "selected" image. you can pass it in as a url parameter..

```
$selected = params['selected'];

// Display results
foreach ($popular->data as $data)
{
  $css = "insta-photo"
  if ($selected == $data) { $css = "insta-photo selected" }
  echo "<a href=\"{$data->images->thumbnail->url}\" class=\"{$css}\">"
  echo "  <img src=\"{$data->images->thumbnail->url}\">"
  echo "<\a>"
}
```